# Guardar una variable de jQuery en localstorage

Tags: jquery, local-storage

Quiero implementar el plugin [*jQuery Text Highlighter*](http://mir3z.github.io/texthighlighter/demos/callbacks.html).

Me gustaría poder guardar lo remarcado en `localstorage`. Así al recargar la página se sigan mostrando las palabras remarcadas.

Este es el código sin editar:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var removeBtn = document.getElementById('remove');
        var sandbox = document.getElementById('sandbox');
        var colors = new ColorPicker(document.querySelector('.color-picker'));
        var hltr = new TextHighlighter(sandbox, {
            onBeforeHighlight: function (range) {
                return window.confirm('Selected text: ' + range + '\nReally highlight?');
            },
            onAfterHighlight: function (range, highlights) {
                window.alert('Created ' + highlights.length + ' highlight(s): ' + highlights.map(function (h) {
                    return '"' + h.innerText + '"';
                }).join(', '));
            },
            onRemoveHighlight: function (hl) {
                return window.confirm('Do you really want to remove: "' + hl.innerText + '"');
            }
        });

        colors.onColorChange(function (color) {
            hltr.setColor(color);
        });

        removeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            hltr.removeHighlights();
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Este es el código editado por mi, pero que no funciona:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var removeBtn = document.getElementById('remove');
        var sandbox = document.getElementById('sandbox');
        var colors = new ColorPicker(document.querySelector('.color-picker'));
        document.getElementById('hltr').value = subr;
        var subr = localStorage.getItem('hltr');
        var hltr = new TextHighlighter(sandbox, {
            onBeforeHighlight: function (range) {
                return window.confirm('Selected text: ' + range + '\nReally highlight?');
            },
            onAfterHighlight: function (range, highlights) {
                window.alert('Created ' + highlights.length + ' highlight(s): ' + highlights.map(function (h) {
                    return '"' + h.innerText + '"';
                }).join(', '));
            },
            onRemoveHighlight: function (hl) {
                return window.confirm('Do you really want to remove: "' + hl.innerText + '"');
            }
        });

        colors.onColorChange(function (color) {
            hltr.setColor(color);
        });

        removeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            hltr.removeHighlights();
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Hola Lhezver. No queda claro qué tipo de ayuda necesitas o que problema tienes. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta para incluir un __[mcve]__ que ayude a comprender tu situación.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el código, pero creo que guardando la variable "hltr" en localstorage y volviéndola a cargar, el texto remarcado se guardaría a pesar de refrescar la pagina, pero la verdad, no se como hacerlo.